# load_files in scikit-learn not loading all files in directory

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, scikit-learn, classification

I have a folder called 'emails' with two subfolders named after the label corresponding to the classification of files they have (spam or notspam emails, all are .txt files). There are 3000 files across the two subfolders. Using load_files:

```
data = load_files('emails', shuffle='False')
print len(data)
print len(data.target)
```

This prints '5' and then '3000'. How can the length of data only be 5 if it found 3000 classification labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is stored in `data.data` and target in `data.target`.
Try `print(len(data.data))` instead.

`load_files()` simply returns a `sklearn.datasets.base.Bunch`, which is a simple data wrapper.
So, `data` is in this format:

```
{
'DESCR': None,
 'data': [],
 'filenames': array(),
 'target': array(),
 'target_names': []
}
```

This is why `len(data)` returns 5.

Hope this helps!